# Why is disk label type dos but the partition system is GPT?

Tags: partition, diskmanagement, fdisk

And how can it be larger than 2TB if it's dos?

```
Disk /dev/sdi: 6000.6 GB, 6000606183424 bytes, 11719933952 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdi1   *           1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is `Protective MBR` feature of GPT in action. Consider a situation when you somehow were able to attach this disk to a Windows 2000 machine. Without this MBR record it would report this disk as uninitialized and offer to create an NTFS partition that would destroy most of the data.
To avoid this a protective MBR is created that contains single primary partition of type 0xEE spanning an entire LBA range available to MBR-based systems. This does not conflict with the GPT scheme as GPT table starts at LBA 1, whereas protective disklabel is at LBA 0.